# Getting data into a jenkins triggered build

Tags: jenkins, hudson, build-automation

I have a Jenkins build that can either be triggered via scheduling, by a user requesting it, or by being called as a build step from other builds. If this build is called as part of another build, it needs to save some information for the larger build to use. I want to pass this information back up by writing to a file. The only problem is having the builds agree on a location to write to.

One approach is to write it to a well known location, but this does not allow several builds to be run in parallel since one will clobber the other.

Another is to add a build parameter to the build that other builds will fill in with a file location to write to. This, to me, seems like a bit of a hack since it means that whenever the build is run, it will need to have a parameter passed in, even if it is just starting with the default value.

The final approach that I considered was having the parent build set an environment variable in the build and having the child check for the existence and content of the variable and act appropriately. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to set this up in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Comment: See the second approach that I considered.

Comment: With the plugin, you can pass named parameters to the build without actually defining them in the child build. Maybe I'm not clear on what you meant?

Comment: I know that it works (and it is how I have it implemented at the moment), but I do not feel that it is a clean enough solution, since now anyone manually running a build has a parameter entry screen that they need to click through (and always accept the defaults for).

Comment: I see, are you talking about the parent build? You shouldn't need to define parameters for that one either, since you could define the params (With default values) as environmental variables via the execute batch or shell command configurations. This would eliminate the extra parameter screen when manually running, but still pass the defaults to the child build.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a combination of archiving artifacts in post build and the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) would do the job.